# Nodemon зависает и не перезагружает проект

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

Недавно столкнулся с проблемой, что nodemon не перезагружает проект при его изменении. Заметил я это при переустановке Windows 10.

Когда я запускаю проект через nodemon, он работает, но как только происходит изменение файла, nodemon зависает на надписи `[nodemon] restarting due to changes...`. При этом, если я попытаюсь закрыть терминал (powershell), то проект перезагрузиться, и через несколько секунд окно закроется.

[image: Запуск nodemon]

Код проекта:

```js
console.log('Привет!')
while (true) {}
```

На Ubuntu всё работает.
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После выключения ПК, на след. день всё заработало.